# PyCharm (pro) - Django console: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: django, pycharm, console

I can't use the Django console because I keep having the following error and can't figure it out what to do.. I've tried extensively to search for a solution online but none it seems to work for me.. probably cause I don't know the reason of the problem

If I don't use the console the app works just fine without any error but I can't do a proper debugging

Here it is the error:

```
/Users/alex/Documents/dev_py/project-crm/venv/bin/python3.10 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=57445
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
import django; print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.extend(['/Users/alex/Documents/dev_py/project-crm', '/Users/alex/Documents/dev_py/project-crm/users', '/Users/alex/Documents/dev_py/project-crm/project_crm', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev'])
if 'setup' in dir(django): django.setup()
import django_manage_shell; django_manage_shell.run("/Users/alex/Documents/dev_py/project-crm")
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.10.0 (v3.10.0:b494f5935c, Oct  4 2021, 14:59:20) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] on darwin
Django 3.2.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/dev_py/project-crm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/dev_py/project-crm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/dev_py/project-crm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/dev_py/project-crm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project-crm'
```

This is the PyCharm console Starting script

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
import django; print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
if 'setup' in dir(django): django.setup()
import django_manage_shell; django_manage_shell.run(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can't have dashes (`-`) in module names.

Comment: The module name is not with a dash, the project folder has it, the main module is called 'project_crm'

Comment: The error message doesn't agree: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project-crm'`

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me, in Pycharm settings go to **Django Console** make sure **Add content roots to PYTHONPATH, Add source to PYTHONPATH** is unmarked. I use Anaconda environment as interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

Adjustment of settings helped:

settings:Languages and Framework:Django

root: path to project

settings: settings.py

manage script: manage.py

folder pattern to track files: migrations

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. This answer is not a proper answer for the original question. Please, consider removing it as you could get downvoted.